# Getting Bourbon without Node, Ruby or anything else

Tags: bourbon, neat

I am a Visual Studio developer who has no need for Ruby, Node, SASS compilers, Minifiers, Grunt or any other such. VS and Web Essentials handles it all for me.

I am just getting into SASS and I like what I see with Bourbon and Neat. But I would rather not install Ruby or Node just to have the .scss include files created for me.

Is there some place I can just download the basic files?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Go to each GitHub page and just get everything in *app/assets/stylesheets*

It appears that is all you actually need to use Bourbon and Neat. everything else appears superfluous, at least to a VS dev.

Is there some other functionality I am missing by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you are missing out on by just downloading those files. The rest of the repository is ruby gems etc. that are not required for your use case.

On a side note I love Neat, it's a great grid system. Have fun!